# OpenSSH WIndows 10 - key_load_private: Permission denied

Tags: windows, permissions, file-permissions, permission-denied, openssh

I've been trying to setup the Windows 10 native openSSH server, however I got stuck with this permission problem, `the log can be found` [here](http://pastebin.com/qmrucdKW), I was following this [setup guide](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/microsoft/how-to-install-the-built-in-windows-10-openssh-server/). I've tried changing the file ownership, giving/removing SSHD/System/Administrator permissions, all to no avail, in one post someone said that the correct permissions should be User/System, however I can't even add any permissions to System or I receive the "Permissions for '[file]' are too open" message. How should I proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to fix it, if you are struggling with permissions just open up PowerShell and type in this:

`Install-Module -Force OPENSSHUtils
set-executionpolicy remotesigned
Import-Module OpenSSHUtils 
Repair-SshdHostKeyPermission -FilePath [your ssh_host_ed25519_key path]`

Regardless to say that authorizing PowerShell to run scripts has security implications.

I now have a hundred other problems to fix with this thing, however this is out of the scope of this question.

Comment: I get `authenticode signature not valid` for the first line.

Comment: @cbartondock Apparently, the OpenSSHUtils module has been deprecated in early 2019, the current recommended guide is this: https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki/Security-protection-of-various-files-in-Win32-OpenSSH